# How Can I Make Right To Left Navbar In My Webform?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm just recently start Asp.net And now I'm gonna to make right to left navbar.
Try some code but all was left to right.

Comment: Share the code you have tried.

Comment: You should post the codes you have tried to help others help you/

Comment: http://bootstrap.rtlcss.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case you using bootstrap use : `class="navbar-right"`

in case you didn't use it you should better use it )

but if you still didn't want to you can use `dir="rtl"` in your nav header tag or creating class and use it like that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <Navbar class="rtl">your text
      ...
   </Navbar>
</body>
</html>
```